# Bloquear acesso direito a arquivo chamado por função Ajax

Tags: ajax, http-request, request

Estou adicionando camadas de proteção em um pequeno sistema que possuo em PHP. Nas requisições via ajax, por exemplo, utilizo o seguinte código abaixo para evitar que pessoas acessem diretamente os arquivos que são chamados via Ajax.

```
if(!$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']){ //AQUI REDIRECIONO O USUÁRIO 'MAL INTENCIONADO' PARA UMA OUTRA PÁGINA }
```

Funciona perfeitamente! No entanto, para um tipo de requisição específica, que se refere ao Upload de imagens, eu não consegui fazer esta validação funcionar. Ele barra o funcionamento do Upload. Segue abaixo o código do javascript:

```
jQuery( "#profile-exp" ).photos( {
                    allowedFileSize: 5242880,
                    url: "../processupload.php",
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: "json",
                    quality: 1,
                    progress: false
                } );
```

O arquivo em questão seria **processupload.php**. Ou seja, gostaria de torná-lo inacessível para quem tentar acessá-lo diretamente via URL.

Já testei uma outra possibilidade, mas também sem sucesso. Segue abaixo:

```
function isHttpRequest() {
if( @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

}

Posteriormente pretendo implementar um Token para aumentar a segurança.

Qual erro estou cometendo a respeito do request acima? Fiz diversas pesquisas no Google e no próprio repositório da StackOverflow.